# Dynamic array program crashes when printing in Nasm Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, printf, nasm, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to write a nasm program that can move and print dynamic arrays using malloc and printf.  The program sometimes crashes and sometimes works when it tries to print an array.  When I edit the code so that it doesn't print anything, the program always works.  The method "movad" sets a dynamic array equal to another array and "setad" sets an array to a static array that was declared at the beginning of the program.  The array variable stores a pointer to a malloced piece of memory that stores the array.  The first dword of the array is the length and the rest is the contents.

Here is the code:

```
%include "io.inc"
CEXTERN malloc

section .data
    fmt: db "%c%c %c%c",0
    start: dd 2
           dd 'a'
           dd 'b'

section .bss
    array1: resd 1
    array2: resd 1
    a: resd 1

section .text
global _main
_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push dword start
    push dword array1
    call setad
    add esp,8
    push dword array1
    push dword array2
    call movad
    add esp,8
    mov ebx,[array2]
    push dword [ebx+8]
    push dword [ebx+4]
    mov ebx,[array1]
    push dword [ebx+8]
    push dword [ebx+4]
    push dword fmt
    call printf
    add esp,20
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
ret

movad:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edi
    push esi
    mov edi,[ebp+8]
    mov esi,[ebp+12]
    mov ebx,[esi]
    push dword [ebx]
    add dword [esp],4
    call malloc
    add esp,4
    mov [edi],eax
    mov ecx,[esi]
    mov ecx,[ecx]
    add ecx,1
    mov edi,[edi]
    mov esi,[esi]
    cld
    rep movsd
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
ret

setad:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push eax
    lea eax,[ebp+12]
    push eax
    push dword [ebp+8]
    call movad
    add esp,8
    pop eax
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
ret
```

How can I make it so that it never crashes when it prints something

Comment: SASM on Windows?

Comment: Yes.  I am using SASM on windows.

Comment: Your code prints `ab ab` . What were you expecting it to print?

Comment: Yes the first ab is array1 and the second ab is array2

Comment: It doesn't crash here.

Comment: Sometimes it crashes and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: I think `malloc` takes number of bytes as argument. If I'm reading the source correctly, you do give it `2+4` (6 bytes), but then you copy 3 dwords (12 bytes), overwriting the allocated memory? But I'm not sure, you use the stack for arguments in such complicated way, that it is very hard to follow it in head, just use debugger to verify all the values are as expected and modified memory is within the legal range, etc. (or simplify the code, if your calls are internal-only, there's no need to put arguments on stack, you can put them in registers (if you don't mind breaking ABI rules locally)).